# Not getting desired output according to input

Tags: c, pointers

I am implementing a simple program to find largest and smallest element from an array using C. But I am getting unexpected output in some cases. Please check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcNnU.png) output. And please check below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int largest(int *input)
{
    int i=0,large=0;
    for(;i<input[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(input[i]>large)
            large=input[i];
    }
    return large;
}

int smallest(int *input)
{
    int i=0,small;
    small=input[i];
    for(;i<input[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(input[i]<small)
            small=input[i];
    }
    return small;
}

void main()
{
    int *input;
    int size,i=0,large,small;
    printf("Enter size of array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("Enter Numbers:\n");
    input=(int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for(;i<size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",input+i);
    }
    large=largest(input);
    printf("Largest element is:%d, ",large);
    small=smallest(input);
    printf("Smallest element is:%d\n",small);
}
```

When I am passing the size to the functions, the program is working correctly.

```
int largest(int *input,int size)
{
    int i=0,large=0;
    for(;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]>large)
            large=input[i];
    }
    return large;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Zk9.png) by implementing above function.

I am not getting what is happening here. Please help me to find solution.

Comment: `i<input[i]!='\0'` --> maybe `input[i] != 0` (`input=(int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));` --> `input=calloc(size+1 , sizeof(int));` )

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes it is working perfect by using calloc function. Thank you for your help. But still i didn't understand why it is not working while using malloc? Can you please explain?

Comment: You are trying to compare with `0`, but it does not exist anywhere in data of inputs.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think there is no matter to comparing with 0. Please check ouput image. I didn't get why it is not working in some case only.

Comment: _why it is not working in some case only._ It is known as UB([undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

Comment: The function interface with no size passed is inferior to the interface with the size passed. You have to use a sentinel value if you don't pass the size explicitly, which limits what you can do (a little). Most often, when you pass an array to a function, you should also pass the operational size of the array.  By operational size, I mean the 'size that is in use' (or 'available for use'); this is often the declared size of the array, but it isn't always the size of the array (you might have allocated 128 elements and only used 97 of them, for instance). Using a sentinel is error prone.

Comment: You might note that your code with the size won't find the largest value if all the entered values are negative.  You should start with `largest = input[0];` and then iterate over the remaining elements of the array (assuming there are any).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main(){
    int count, i, j, k;
    float all_number[15],temp;
    printf("\n Enter the number of input : ");
    scanf("%d",&count);
    for(i=0;i< count;i++){
        printf("\n Enter %d element : ",i);
        scanf("%f",&all_number[i]);
    }
    for(j=0; j<count ; j++){
        for(k = j+1; k <count; k++){
            if(all_number[j] > all_number[k]){
                temp = all_number[j];
                all_number[j] = all_number[k];
                all_number[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

     printf("\n lowest %d element : %f",i,all_number[0]);
     printf("\n highest%d element : %f",i,all_number[count]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for helping. Please consider improving your answer by explaining what the solution is. A comment inside the code is an easy way of doing this. Code-only answers are less appreciated here. You might enjoy getting your first badge for taking the [tour] by the way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Answer] pages soon.  Generally, it is a good idea to explain a bit about what you are doing.  It isn't clear that it's OK to sort the data; it certainly isn't necessary to sort the data to determine the largest and smallest.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, coming from you I consider that a compliment.